# Nginx / GoDaddy - Mask IP without masking path

Tags: nginx, path, mask

Im using nginx to set up my server at some IP "12.12.12.12", and i have a domain at GoDaddy like "domain.com".
GoDaddy offers the possibility to mask the "12.12.12.12" with "domain.com" but it will mask the full path ("12.12.12.12/some/path" would be just "domain.com").

***What i need***:

I need to mask ONLY the IP with the domain.
So "12.12.12.12/path/nice" would become "domain.com/path/nice" and so on.
I need the site to be accessible by "domain.com" (nobody would write the numeric IP), and be able to see the path navigation.

***What i tried***:

In the GoDaddy masking/redirecting/DNS "A" options i had no success, it just masks all the path, or just redirects.

In Nginx y tried "rewrite" and "return 301" ways but they just make an infinite loop, as 12.12.12.12 forwards to domain.com, and domain.com forwards to 12.12.12.12.

Thanks a lot in advance!